# Using postman to Send Post several times a day

Tags: postman, arduino-yun

I'm working on a Arduino personal project.

With thingspeak + postman i'm being able to **manually** send Tweets. I want postman to send tweets automatically when ever my API field updates.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman).

With Newman you can run your Postman requests on the command line. Just setup a cronjob which would automate your newman call.